# Java memory usage goes up after each write/read from file. Why?

Tags: java, memory, save, loading, bufferedreader

I coded a map editor for tile-based games and everything is running fine, except one thing: Whenever i write to a textfile or read from a textfile, the memory usage goes up drastically and never goes down or stays the same even if i close the input/output streams.

Here is an example code of loading:

```
public static void loadMap(String mapName, int width) {
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("./" + mapName + ".map")))) {
        Level.width = width;
        Level.height = width;
        String sCurrentLine;
        int lineCount = 0;
        int length = width * width;
        tiles = new int[length];

        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] dataArray = sCurrentLine.split(",");
            for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++) {
                tiles[i + lineCount * width] = Integer.parseInt(dataArray[i]);
            }
            lineCount++;
        }
        br.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

        isLoading = false;
    }
```

Head of the class where tiles is stored:

```
public class Level extends GameState {

public static int width, height;
Pallette tilePallette;

public static Map<Integer, Tile> tileMap = new HashMap<Integer, Tile>();

public static int[] tiles;
```

And last but not least:
level = new Level(64, 64);
gets called in thread.

Can anybody enlighten me, why the memory usage goes up after each load?
I know the mapsize is very large (4096x4096) but i tried it in all sizes, it doesnt matter, the memory usage goes up everytime i load or save.
I dont want my program to consume over 4GB ram after 50 saves.

Comment: First of all: this is 2015; why do you still use `File`? And why don't you use try-with-resources?

Comment: I fixed that now, it was not the problem :) but thx for pointing that out.

Comment: Most of the memory here seems to be used for the `tiles`array. But we cannot tell from the code you posted what you do with this array, what is its scope, etc

Comment: there is one big array that stores the whole map(integers). 
but it is only stored once and gets overwritten on each load.
why would the program use more memory for an array if it only gets overwritten each time i load? it never gets bigger.
More interesting is the fact, that the program uses more memory whenever i write the whole tiles[] array to the file.

Comment: and tiles is static, may that be the problem?

Comment: I would share a minimal test case that reproduces it (main method that calls this in a loop, perhaps). I may be missing something, but I'm not sure that anything in this code snippet actually explains the memory usage. Are you sure you're not retaining either a copy of the tiles array or some other resource?

Comment: i am sure ) thx, i will provide more code! i hope someone can help me then